# How can I make a directive if I have only two if conditions ? - Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

Hi Is there any way I can Make a directive for this `html`. I have to checks if language type is `arabic`then apply `float:right` else if language type is `english` then apply nothing.

```
<div ng-show="show_div">
  <div class="aa-properties-content-head mg-bt-10 font-size-13" ng-if="$root.lg_type =='en'">
    <div data-ng-repeat="variant in variants">
      <div class="col-md-{{columns}} col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <label for="text">{{variant.name}}:</label>
        <input type="text" name="variant_value{{$index}}" class="form-control" ng-model="variant.variant_value" ng-blur="search_category()" placeholder="{{$root.translated_labels.dashboard.enter}} {{variant.name}}" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="30" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-{{columns}}">
      <label for="item_price">{{$root.tl['product-variant'].price}}:</label>
      <input class="form-control" name="price" ng-model="search_price" placeholder="{{$root.translated_labels.dashboard.item_price}}" ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="20" id="item_price" type="text" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-{{columns}}" id="prod_type_dd">
      <label for="product_type_id">{{$root.tl.product.product_type_id}}:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="product_type_id" placeholder="{{$root.translated_labels.dashboard.select_type}}" uib-typeahead="producttype.id as producttype.name for producttype in producttype_data | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:4" typeahead-input-formatter="formatLabel($model)"
      class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="aa-properties-content-head mg-bt-10 font-size-13" ng-if="$root.lg_type =='ar'">
    <div data-ng-repeat="variant in variants">
      <div class="col-md-{{columns}} col-sm-12 col-xs-12 float-right">
        <label for="text">{{variant.name}}:</label>
        <input type="text" name="variant_value{{$index}}" class="form-control" ng-model="variant.variant_value" ng-blur="search_category()" placeholder="{{$root.translated_labels.dashboard.enter}} {{variant.name}}" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="30" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-{{columns}} float-right">
      <label for="item_price">{{$root.tl['product-variant'].price}}:</label>
      <input class="form-control" name="price" ng-model="search_price" placeholder="{{$root.translated_labels.dashboard.item_price}}" ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="20" id="item_price" type="text" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-{{columns}} float-right" id="prod_type_dd">
      <label for="product_type_id">{{$root.tl.product.product_type_id}}:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="product_type_id" placeholder="{{$root.translated_labels.dashboard.select_type}}" uib-typeahead="producttype.id as producttype.name for producttype in producttype_data | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:4" typeahead-input-formatter="formatLabel($model)"
      class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I pass the data of `controller` to directive ? I am already loading data from controller but i dont know how to pass it in directive, and then get it again to pass into controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean doing something this way ?

```
.directive('alignmentBlock', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
       if(scope.arabic)
         elem.css({'float': 'right'});
    }
  };
});
```

Assessing that you update a boolean scope variable whether the user switch to arabic/non-arabic.

And then in HTML you could just use this directive like this :

```
<div alignmentBlock>
  <p>your text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: okaye if i have arabic value in rootscope how would I do this

Comment: you can as well pass the root scope into the link function scope : juste replace scope by rootScope